# PCA applied to mixed values

Tags: python, algorithm, boolean, pca

I have a question about how to perform a PCA algorithm with mixed data in Python.
I have a table with several columns. The first one is a number, and all the others are booleans values, represented as 1 or 0.

I have to use the PCA algorithm, even though I read that it may not be the best alternative to reduce dimensionalities in this case.

My question is: Do I have to use all the data at the same level? Should I do some specific treatment for the numeric value, and a different treatment for the booleans?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, to discuss Data Science related question please use [data science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Stackoverflow if for problems related to code. Thank you